# Can we package our existing HTML5 JS App for Windows 8

Tags: windows-8

I have read some posts on S/O and also around the web. We are producing a HTML5 JS based web app that runs on the web. We are packaging it up for Google apps, and also for phonegap.

Can we package this app for windows 8? Of course, I appreciate it won't use the windows 8 features. But, will the app run none the less, as it stands. So that we can place it in the store and build out windows 8 features as we move forward.

I appreciate this is a slightly non-concise question, but I guess the real point is what is our quickest route to take our existing HTML 5, CSS, JS App and deploy it in the store and get it working on this platform.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general, the answer is yes.  The transition is not seamless, but you will be able to use a ton, if not all, of the application artifacts in Win8.  A good test is if you can run it in IE10, you can run the app as a Win8 app.  Again, this is a very broad brush - things you need to worry about are things like all scripts files need to be local (no CDN), changes to web and security contexts, and the fact that Win8 is a horizontal paradigm whereas most web apps are vertical.  But in general, you should be able to make the move.  Usual caveat - your mileage will vary.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, although not recommended, you can package your existing app for Win8. You'll need to add a few bits of code though. The minimum would be to embed your app's start/init code within WinJS's first promise callback, like so:

```
args.setPromise(WinJS.UI.processAll().then(function () {
// your init code
}
```

You'll also need to create a couple of icons for the start screen and an image for your app's launch screen.

It is possible that you'll run into a few issues, like some security related restrictions, where you'll have to modify your code to use some native WinJS functions. This all depends on you app's implementation.

Comment: WinJS.UI.ProcessAll is only needed if you are going to use WinJS UI controls.  WinJS.Application.start is required if you want to wire into WinJS application events, in particular things like suspend.  There is no hard requirement that you use WinJS at all - it just makes supporting a lot of things that make an app Windows 8 friendly a lot easier

Answer (score 3):

You can also check Microsoft's guidelines for migrating a web app to win8, here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465143